# cudaEventSynchronize behavior under different circumstances

Tags: asynchronous, cuda

I have a question regarding the CUDA call cudaEventSynchronize.

AFAIK, it activelly polls the event, thus consuming CPU cycles. If I would like to make it synchronous so CPU can be yielded as I can do with kernel executions, how could I do it?.

More specifically, what would be the expected behaviour under:

- using CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 env variable.
- using cudaDeviceScheduleBlockingSync
- using cudaDeviceScheduleYield

I have been experiencing strange behaviours and need some help to elucidate this. Nvidia information on specific technical aspects are very reluctant to help with this... I suppose implementation details must be kept secret.

Thanks in advance,

Jose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want cudaEventSynchronize to use blocking synchronization than you will need to create your event using 


`cudaError_t cudaEventCreateWithFlags (cudaEvent_t  event, unsigned int ﬂags)`

and pass `cudaEventBlockingSync` as the flag.

Comment: This is a good suggestion.  It's a matter of scope - CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING affects all CUDA programs (so should not be used for anything but debug purposes) and the device flags affect all synchronization done in the context. Specifying the event flag causes that specific event to use interrupts for synchronization, reducing CPU overhead.